# how to find pictures of landmarks from address/location(latitude and longitude)

Tags: thumbnails, street-address, panoramio

I have a set of latitude and longitude of places like restaurants/landmarks etc.
and even their addresses.
i wanted to find out their **pictures** using these details i.e. **LOCATION(lat/long)** or the **ADDRESS** and i am not being able to do so.

Pictures as in the thumbnails or pictures that we see if we view these places on google maps.
i got the latitude and longitude using HTTP requests and also preferably would like to get the pictures similarly.
i have a clue about **panoramio api** but that is not accurate.
Any idea about anything else?
the latitude and longitude has been found using Google geo-location api.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add latitude longitude values and tag for places i.e "restaurants" in this panoramio JavaScript API.

this Panoramio JavaScript API widget create a bounding box around a lat/long pair and then returning all photos with in those bounds with your tag.

Another type of Panoramio JavaScript API widget in which you can also change background color with [example and code is here](http://codespk.blogspot.com/2013/10/panoramio-javascript-api-widget-example.html).

More HTML and JavaScript API [examples are here](http://discoverworldz.blogspot.com)

It does not show in composing mood.It show after publishing.

```
  <div dir="ltr" style="text-align: center;" trbidi="on">
    <script src="https://ssl.panoramio.com/wapi/wapi.js?v=1&amp;hl=en"></script>
    <div id="wapiblock" style="float: right; margin: 10px 15px"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var myRequest = {
      'tag': 'kahna',
      'rect': {'sw': {'lat': -30, 'lng': 10.5}, 'ne': {'lat': 50.5, 'lng': 30}}
    };
      var myOptions = {
      'width': 300,
      'height': 200
    };
    var wapiblock = document.getElementById('wapiblock');
    var photo_widget = new panoramio.PhotoWidget('wapiblock', myRequest, myOptions);
    photo_widget.setPosition(0);
    </script>
    </div>
```